# xslt failing if xml has an extra xml tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetDetailsResponse xmlns="http://www.test.org.za/testservice/">
            <GetDetailsResult>
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
                <Name>Paul</Name>
                <LastName>Smith</LastName>          
            </GetDetailsResult>
        </GetDetailsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have XSLT that tries to get the Name and LastName tags from the XML

But this fails because of the extra `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` tag.

Is there any way to get around this

Comment: What is the idea to have a second XML preamble in the middle of the file? You you want to change the encoding in the middle of the file?

Comment: It's coming from a vendor's service that way. They refuse to fix it

Answer (score 2):

Your input file isn't well-formed XML, so there is no way to process it using XSLT (or using any other tool designed to handle XML).

You need to fix the problem at source: find out where the data is being produced, and fix that process so it generates well-formed XML.

Answer (score 0):

LibXML has the option to recover broken XML files. This makes it possible to remove the PI node. But it will not fix your encoding problem and I doubt that any tool will be able to fix it. You probably have to write a XML parser from scratch.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::Iterator;
use Data::Dumper;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
$parser->recover(1);
my $xml = $parser->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);
my $iter= XML::LibXML::Iterator->new($xml->documentElement);
while ($iter->nextNode) {
  my $node = $iter->current();
  if (ref $node eq 'XML::LibXML::PI') {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
  }
}
print $xml->toString();

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetDetailsResponse xmlns="http://www.test.org.za/testservice/">
            <GetDetailsResult>
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
                <Name>Paul</Name>
                <LastName>Smith</LastName>
            </GetDetailsResult>
        </GetDetailsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```